# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have Spring Boot Application. I also use Spring Security and Thymeleaf.\
I have a piece of code where I get you tube videos from database and apply it in my thymeleaf template.
If I open dev tools in browser(any) I get error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' from origin
>   'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value
>   of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not
>   be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
>   The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

If I remove a piece of code with You Tube  videos errors will be gone.

**How Can I resolve this error?**

[image: Browser IMage]

Spring Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/handlers/access-denied.html")
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(

                // статика
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/fonts/**",
                "../libs/**",
                "/images/**"
        );
    }
}
```

Template:

```html
<div class="video-container">
        <div class="video-item" th:each="video : ${videos}">
            <iframe th:src="${video.url}"
                    frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <h3 th:text="${video.title}"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```